# Zend_Paginator links with query params

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

Could you please tell me how to make link with Zend_Paginator like this:
http://url/controller/action?id=47&page=2.
I want to add to url additional paramter to the query of url like url?id=value, not paramater like this one:
url/controller/action/param/value. Could you also tell please how to pass a variable for view to partial aside from page.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not usual here to edit a question to add an other question once you have started to get answer, you should have opened an other one. Look at this link for an answer http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the default view helper Url that is made for handling that.

you can generate your url with the following :

```
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'controllerName',
                      'action'     => 'actionName',
                      'param1'     => 'param1',
                      'param2'     => 'param2));
```

If you omit some of the params, the helper will reuse those that were in the query url

So, with Zend_Paginator you go this way :

```
$pages = $this->paginator->getPages();

// previous
echo $this->url(array('page' => ($pages->current -1)));

// current
echo $this->url(array('page' => ($pages->current)));

// next
echo $this->url(array('page' => ($pages->current +1)));
```

** EDIT **

Exemple to reflect my first comment

```
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName')) . '?user=' . $id . '&page=' . $pageNumber
```

Comment: It will add partamaters but I need to add to url like this url?id=value.

Comment: you could just produce your base url with the helper and concatenate your string to it to make it like : controller/action?id=value

Comment: I think you're right, it looks like variables I can pass through the fourth parameter of paginationControl.

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand this post(s) correctly ... this is your solution for making a $_GET or $_POST value persistent for each subsequent page load within a Paginator'ed set of results?  i have a search function that's returning results but when i try to paginate through the results the subsequent page loads unsets that $_POST variable and i start returning all of the results because the wildcard search becomes `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%%'`.  not what i want

EDIT: i am loading the keywords into zend_cache() and calling them back out on page load by passing the id of the cache ( the md5() value of the keyword ) by way of the URI.  if anyone's interested i'll post the code

Comment: So the url of each page looked something like http://url/view?id=57&page=2&rows=25&filterby=2&filter=Allen&status=1 for example.